# ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext() always returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i'm running a web-app with `spring-boot` and have to use external articfacts which are using `ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()` to get some beans from.
But it always returns `null`.
According to the `spring-boot`documentation the parent application context is not a `WebApplicationContext`. Is there any other way to access the `WebApplicationContext` via `ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ContextLoader` isn't really applicable to Spring Boot applications (or any with Servlet 3.0 dynamic initialization). Spring Boot *does* set up the `ServletContext` so that `WebApplicationContextUtils` can locate the web context. Your external artifacts really ought not to be using `ContextLoader` static methods since it makes assumptions about the way the app is deployed. Can you change them? Or work out another way to set their state?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't change them. I just could issue a change request. It's about some custom made servlets which initialize some beans via the ```ContextLoader```. So as long as they use the ```ContextLoader``` i'm forced to implement these Servlets on my own?

Comment: I guess you could write a custom `ContextLoaderListener` instead of using `SpringBootServletInitializer` or `SpringApplication` directly. The listener would extend `ContextLoader` (or the existing listener) but load the context using `SpringApplication`. There's a prototype [here](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/legacy/context/web/SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be a great help.

Comment: is there anything similar for webflux?

Comment: This link is not alive. Could you share the code here please?

Comment: That code is unmaintained. Probably doesn't work with latest versions. If you still need to see it, it's still there: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy/blob/main/spring-boot-legacy/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/legacy/context/web/SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java